# Types incompatibility with flow type

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have a code (don't consider `moment`, I've added stub for flow)

```js
/* @flow */
const moment = (a?: any) => a
const badDateRegex = /(\d|\d\d)\/(\d|\d\d)\/\d{4}/

const makeDatePretty = (date: string) => {
  if (badDateRegex.test(date)) {
    const [m, d, y] = date.split('/')
    return `${y}-${m}-${d}`
  }
  return date
}
const format = 'MM/YYYY'

const convertDateToMY = (date: Object | string) => moment.isMoment(date)
  ? typeof date.format === 'function' && date.format(format)
  : typeof date === 'string'
    ? moment(makeDatePretty(date))
    : date != null
      ? moment(date)
      : moment()

const convertDatesToMY = (dates: string[] | string | Object[], separator: string = ' - ') =>
  Array.isArray(dates)
    ? dates.map(convertDateToMY).join(separator)
    : convertDatesToMY(dates)
```

And flow throws error

```js
22: const convertDatesToMY = (dates: string[] | string | Object[], separator: string = ' - ') =>
                                     ^ string. This type is incompatible with
22: const convertDatesToMY = (dates: string[] | string | Object[], separator: string = ' - ') =>
                                                         ^ object type
22: const convertDatesToMY = (dates: string[] | string | Object[], separator: string = ' - ') =>
                                                         ^ object type. This type is incompatible with
22: const convertDatesToMY = (dates: string[] | string | Object[], separator: string = ' - ') =>
                                     ^ string
```

What did I missed in types declaration ?

[Link of Flow Playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5gC2chAplgQLxgAUAhgPwBcYdWAngJRiUB8rGbPjAAjOgBMAInTykASqQDmpAB48wwGgB1xAHx07OWzTv3jDxnQG8ALAF80g3AUJ0A1qWmyACgCdSeHjs6jTiMqQs+L4AlliK3HxgVqhgYNFQtGJS4QrKKgB0svih4ZzcyampmM5gANqEADRg4k3sALrqYbL5OAAOMNF4NADkwMOcKZX+eACuvlhgAAYAJFbsdgC0q4Sbq+J2i5N2k9NzC12kqMfVwlBwvq5UYMMAsi-AAJpfH8OoTsLVABupF8eC8pAAKnAXh8QhcWAB5EQAK1I6AIujAUVi8R4-GIZAo+WiOBeJHIQwuE1SDDAQV6pDgGQu+TuDxkPEo1GGUBmWHR0WwwzAADIRc1wqz7o8aGzHtSwCx6YzmeFOdzsXFfpUwLSCRSaK4POC-AEgiVZGVJqkWBcwABCahYGYwGDWyp68kUC2kBU6lj670Tf4EIEgsHhHBQmFwyORPAxOK1DqYzWKMCYpGo9HJpo4Ui9Oi+GT3eOJ9PcsAbZ4JXiTACCvmL7GJOEbzZ9OD9uolRXyrl6NDDoPB0Y+nHyyLgsRo+cLxbw927LGHEaKY87nCAA)

Comment: It's not the same, but should work fine in your case: `Array<string|Object> | string`.

Comment: @FelixKling make an answer from your comment, it's right

Comment: @FelixKling, why did the array notation fail while the `Array<>` syntax worked ?